# magento backend user role assigned field

Tags: backend

I've searched the archives but cannot find the answer to the following simple question concerning the magento backend. When I go to System -> Permissions -> Users -> Add New User -> User Role I understand I can assign zero roles or one role to each user. With zero roles assigned the user will not be able to log in. Once I assign the role (creating the role if needed), the user can log in and perform operations corresponding to that role via a restricted user interface. So far so good.

Here is what I don't understand: what does the Assigned: { Any, Yes, No } drop-down box. I've left it to the default (Any) just above the roles column, where the selected role can be found.

What is the meaning of the Assigned drop-down box on this screen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That field is used for search. if you select `yes` and press search then you should see in the grid only the assigned role. if you select `No`...I'll let you find out what happens.

Comment: OK. Sorry for the silly question. Now I understand. I can type a role name in the "Role Name" field and pressing search will perform a search on the list of role names and return those role names which match the text specified (presumably using a 'LIKE' SQL query). With "Any" assigned all matches are displayed, with "Yes" only roles which have been assigned to at least one user are displayed, and with "No" only those roles which have not been assigned to any user are displayed. You need to click on the "Search" button in order to see the results. Thanks a lot.