# UI: Backend Catalog -> Manage Products -> edit product (Related Products, Up-Sells, Cross-Sells)

Tags: admin, backend, catalogsearch

Sorry if I must ask this stupid question, but I cannot figure out the meaning of
the following user interface element in the backend (Magento 1.8.0.0):

Under any of

> Catalog -> Manage Products -> edit product (Related Products,
>   Up-Sells, Cross-Sells)

the first column of the search fields displays a check box (which is checked by
default) and the value "Yes" is selected (the three values available are "Any",
"Yes", and "No"). Furthermore when I click the "Reset Filter" button the
checkbox disappears and the value of the drop-down menu which contained
"Yes" changes to "Any". However I cannot figure out what the checkbox
means, and also cannot figure out what the value of the drop-down
menu below it from which it is possible to select "Any", "Yes",
or "No" means. Could someone please explain to me the meaning
of the checkbox field and the drop-down menu field?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox on each line in the grids is a way to mark if the product listed on that line is in relation with the product you are creating/editing (up-sell, cross-sell, related).
In general a grid in Magento has the following elements.

1. The first row represents the column headers. These headers give meaning to the columns.
2. The second row contains the filter options. It allows you to filter by any column that supports filtering. This row is not mandatory. It can be omitted on some grids (see the Reports grids for example).
3. The rest of the rows represent the entities listed in the grid.

In the case of the relations tabs (and others) the dropdown with the values `Any`, `Yes`, `No` represents a way to filter the grid (because it's on the filter row of the grid).
If you select `Any` it means that there is no filter on the grid for the column with checkboxes.
If you select `Yes` and press `Search` you will see in the grid only the rows that have the checkbox checked. (Of course the rest of the filters apply if you have any).
If you select `No` and press `Search` you will see in the grid only the rows that have the checbox uncheched.
It's somehow similar to [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/9367/146). The difference is that in this case there are checkboxes not radio buttons.
**[EDIT]**
The purpose of the checkbox above the `Any/Yes/No` filter is to check/uncheck easier all visible checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation was crystal-clear. The only thing missing from the explanation is the purpose of the checkbox above the {Any, Yes, No} drop-down menu in the search options row (and the reason I could not understand its behavior is I only had one product in the catalog). When this checkbox is checked, all product items appearing in the search result grid below become checked. Similarly, when this checkbox is unchecked, all product items appearing in the search result grid below become unchecked.

Comment: @JohnSonderson. Right. The purpose of that checkbox is to check/uncheck all visible checkboxes. As simple as that. I've added it to the answer. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: Perhaps the confusing thing about it, which could be improved in future versions of Magento, is the following: if the checkbox in the upper right (on the property names row) is unchecked, and below it the drop-down menu displays Yes, and no items are displayed in the search result grid below it, and I click the checkbox, then a floppy disk icon appears on the left sidebar named "Related Products", "Up-sells", or "Cross-sells". However, since the list was empty, there is no change to the Product information, so that floppy disk should not appear there. That is what was confusing me. Thks again.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is creating product relations: simple related products will usually show on the product page or cart page. cross sell is another relation -- across the catalog -- more products like this, up sell means higher value products related to this one. 
as of the UI
change the YES to any and then you see all the products. you change any product to YES and that means it is now related to the product you are editing